# Does Control.Invoke pump messages?

Tags: .net

Does Control.Invoke() continue to pump messages in the thread that it was called from while blocked? (System.Windows.Forms)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Invoke is blocking - the entire thread will block until the call to Invoke returns.

There is also [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) which is non-blocking.

Answer (score 3):

No.  It requires the UI thread to do the pumping.  If it doesn't then Invoke() won't complete.  Classic source of deadlock btw.  Diagnose with Debug + Windows + Threads, check the main thread call stack.