# Control.Invoke() and Control.BeginInvoke() - Where are the past parameters stored? How is it disposed?

Tags: c#, .net, invoke, begininvoke

I have done a lot of reading about Control.Invoke and Control.BeginInvoke and understand that Invoke is like `SendMessage()` and `BeginInvoke` is like `PostMessage()`, but I do not understand where the parameter list passed via `new object[] { arg, arg, arg, ...}` is stored. During a conventional call, parameters are pushed to the stack and popped within the called function, then the call frame is recovered from the stack after exit, I assume releasing any references to any heap objects, allowing them to be collected. So, where is the pushed stack date for `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` stored? How does it get disposed once the method called exits?

Also, I have successfully invoked a control method without loading a new object array with the pass parameters. Why would this work? Better yet, since it does work, why would all the examples I have ever seen show it with a new object array?

This is what I have always seen and used:

```
BeginInvoke(FormReceiveEvent, new object[] { Event, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3 });
```

But this works too:

```
BeginInvoke(FormReceiveEvent, Event, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3);
```

Any information and comments are always appreciated...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `object[]` containing the parameters is stored internally by the BeginInvoke method while it asynchronously invokes the target delegate. The reference to the array is released once the asynchronous call completes, allowing the array and its contents (assuming they are not otherwise reachable) to be collected.

The `BeginInvoke(FormReceiveEvent, Event, Arg1, Arg2, Arg3);` form works because the second parameter to `BeginInvoke` is defined as [`params object[]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx). This means that if you don't explicitly create an array, the compiler will do it for you. Therefore, the two calls are identical in terms of runtime behaviour.

---

A note on terminology: in the context of .Net, to say that an object is "disposed" typically means that the object implements `IDisposable` and that its `IDisposable.Dispose` method got called. In the context of `Control.BeginInvoke` and `Control.Invoke`, that does not happen.

After the asynchronous call finishes, the reference to the `object[]` is released so it can be collected, but if any of its members implement `IDisposable`, the `IDisposable.Dispose` method is *not* called. The object's resources will not be released until it is collected (or someone else disposes it).

Comment: Great points. Sorry for the misuse of dispose. So as long as there are no longer references to the object, and GC occurs, it will call dispose if IDisposble is implimented? Thanks again.

Comment: @CCS: If an object that implements `IDisposable` contains any unmanaged resources, those should be released by the object's finalizer as well, so they will still be released if the object is not disposed before it is collected. The usual pattern is to have a `Dispose(bool)` method, and the `IDisposable.Dispose` method calls `Dispose(true)`, and the finalizer calls `Dispose(false)`.

Answer (score 0):

Not always its true that a passed param is stored on stack. Only if its valuetype its stored. Other wise a ref is stored there looking at heap for that ref type.

In this case, the same holds good too. And difference b.w object array and passing as individual array, i guess its the allocation on stack. If you pass them seperately more stack space is allocated. Where as, a ref is allocated in stack pointing out to N number of array objects in heap.

Feel free to correct me.

Comment: Value types need not be passed on the stack. The jitter may choose to enregister them.

Comment: Never mind eric, i got yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865604/where-in-memory-are-nullable-types-stored/2866346#2866346 
Well after reading that, can i say the storage of valuetypes are mostly on stack but rarely on else where which could be .nets implementation secrets?

Answer (score 0):

When passing some object to `Control.Invoke` or `Control.BeginInvoke`, you are passing a parameters to a **"method"**, it is no different from passing parameters to any method. However if you curios about the `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke` implementation you can check it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948643/curious-about-the-implementation-of-control-invoke/6948681#6948681).

For the second part of the question the signiture of `BeginInvoke` is:

```
BeginInvoke(Delegate method, params object[] args);
```

So you are asking about the [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) keyword, which is a special keyword that allow you to pass `n` arguments or array of specific type to method.

> The params keyword lets you specify a method parameter that takes a variable number of arguments.
>   You can send a comma-separated list of arguments of the type specified in the parameter declaration, or an array of arguments of the specified type. You also can send no arguments.